# Redirect Wordpress main domain index.php to a page (same domain)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Just a quick query. Checking your thoughts on how to redirect a Wordpress main domain index.php to a page (same domain). For example, my WordPress domain is `https://maindomain.com` which is the same as `https://maindomain.com/index.php`. I prefer to redirect permanently to `https://maindomain.com/page/` via `.htaccess`. All other pages should work as intended, and this is specific only to the WordPress index page. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Try this***

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ https://maindomain.com/page/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Would like to try this, thank you. Just to double-check, will this only redirect the Wordpress index.php and home page, for example, `https://maindomain.com/index.php` and `https://maindomain.com/`to redirect to `https://maindomain.com/page/`? I assume that other pages like `https://maindomain.com/page2/` or `https://maindomain.com/category/`or `https://maindomain.com/post/` will not be affected. I intend for this redirect to affect the index page only and nothing else. Please clarify.

Comment: Did you get the result ?

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks a bunch! It works without affecting the other pages. Only the main index gets redirected.